# Adobe Flex 4 XML validation against XSD

Tags: xml, schema, flex4, validation

Is there any way using any of the standard XML tools or E4X tools in Flex 4 (Adobe Air WindowedApp) for me to validate an XML against an XSD schema I have created?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is any tool for XML and XSD schema validation. I have written code for it manually for my previous projects...